# Portfolio tracker in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, yahoo-finance

I'm making a portfolio tracker using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) remote data function, however, I'm running into a problem passing in multiple stock names and tickers.

I would like to create separate data frames by the company name and I'm attempting to use `**kwargs`, but am a little fuzzy on how it works.

I think I'm pretty close but missing something somewhere.

```
def portfolio(startDateYE, startDateMonth, startDateDay, end_dateYE,
              end_dateMonth, end_dateDay,  **kwargs):
    '''insert desired started and ending date as 2014,1,1 and key value pairs
    of the stock you would like to look up, i.e. ford = "f" '''
    start = datetime.datetime(startDateYE, startDateMonth, startDateDay)
    end = datetime.datetime(end_dateYE, end_dateMonth, end_dateDay)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        key = web.DataReader("%s" % value,'yahoo', start, end)
```

Example of how I would pass in the variable amount of variables:

```
portfolio(2010,1,1,2011,1,1,ford="f",google="googl")
```

The output I'm aiming for is:

```
In [6]: ford.ix['2010-01-04']
Out[6]: 
Open         1.017000e+01
High         1.028000e+01
Low          1.005000e+01
Close        1.028000e+01
Volume       6.085580e+07
Adj Close    8.755953e+00
Name: 2010-01-04 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

EDITED:

```
def portfolio(startDateYE, startDateMonth, startDateDay, end_dateYE,
              end_dateMonth, end_dateDay,  **kwargs):
    '''insert desired started and ending date as 2014,1,1 and key value pairs
    of the stock you would like to look up, i.e. ford = "f" '''
    start = datetime.datetime(startDateYE, startDateMonth, startDateDay)
    end = datetime.datetime(end_dateYE, end_dateMonth, end_dateDay)
    results = {}  # this is an empty dictionary
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        results[key] = web.DataReader(value, key, 'yahoo', start, end)

    print(results)
```

EDIT:

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     34 '''
     35 
---> 36 portfolio(2012,1,1,2013,1,1,facebook="f",google="googl")
     37 
     38 # Adjusted_f = f['Adj Close']

in portfolio(startDateYE, startDateMonth, startDateDay, end_dateYE, end_dateMonth, end_dateDay, **kwargs)
     27     results = {}  # this is an empty dictionary
     28     for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
---> 29         results[key] = web.DataReader(value, key, 'yahoo', start, end)
     30 
     31 '''

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.pyc in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause)
     86     ff = DataReader("F-F_ST_Reversal_Factor", "famafrench")
     87     """
---> 88     start, end = _sanitize_dates(start, end)
     89 
     90     if data_source == "yahoo":

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/data.pyc in _sanitize_dates(start, end)
    104 def _sanitize_dates(start, end):
    105     from pandas.core.datetools import to_datetime
--> 106     start = to_datetime(start)
    107     end = to_datetime(end)
    108     if start is None:

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 else:
     90                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         return wrapper
     93     return _deprecate_kwarg

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.pyc in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, coerce, unit, infer_datetime_format)
    285                         yearfirst=yearfirst,
    286                         utc=utc, box=box, format=format, exact=exact,
--> 287                         unit=unit, infer_datetime_format=infer_datetime_format)
    288 
    289

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.pyc in _to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, freq, infer_datetime_format)
    414         return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    415 
--> 416     return _convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]
    417 
    418

/Users/andrewclark/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.pyc in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name)
    400                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    401             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 402                 raise e
    403 
    404     if arg is None:

ValueError: Unknown string format

Thank you!

Comment: This is a purely programming question, I will hence migrate it to [se]. You would still need to enhance it by defining the full signature of your method (what does it return, i.e. how do you get your `ford` variable and what is the `web` module you're referring to).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep overwriting the key value, so you are effectively only saving the last data set.

You should track the keys and their results separately, something like this:

```
results = {}  # this is an empty dictionary
for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
    results[key] = web.DataReader(value, key, start, end)

print(results)
```

Comment: I tried this code but now it is giving me a "ValueError: Unknown string format" error. Any thoughts? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you post the entire error message? (Update your question).